# How come my <td> elements are not displaying at 100vw?

Tags: html, css, html-table, width, viewport

I am following the FreeCodeCamp curriculum for responsive web design. I am on the module "Learn More About CSS Pseudo Selectors By Building A Balance Sheet" step 53. The first instruction is to set the width of td elements inside the tbody to 100vw. My expectation is that when I do this, the width of each td should be equal to the width of the viewport. However, this is not the case. Can someone explain why? I will provide the source code below, though there's quite a bit:

```css
span[class~="sr-only"] {
  border: 0 !important;
  clip: rect(1px, 1px, 1px, 1px) !important;
  clip-path: inset(50%) !important;
  height: 1px !important;
  width: 1px !important;
  position: absolute !important;
  overflow: hidden !important;
  white-space: nowrap !important;
  padding: 0 !important;
  margin: -1px !important;
}

html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: #0a0a23;
}

h1 {
  max-width: 37.25rem;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 1.5rem 1.25rem;
}

h1 .flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column-reverse;
  gap: 1rem;
}

h1 .flex span:first-of-type {
  font-size: 0.7em;
}

h1 .flex span:last-of-type {
  font-size: 1.2em;
}

section {
  max-width: 40rem;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 2px solid #d0d0d5;
}

#years {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  position: sticky;
  z-index: 999;
  top: 0;
  background: #0a0a23;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 0.5rem calc(1.25rem + 2px) 0.5rem 0;
  margin: 0 -2px;
}

#years span[class] {
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 4.5rem;
  text-align: right;
}

.table-wrap {
  padding: 0 0.75rem 1.5rem 0.75rem;
}

span {
  font-weight: normal;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 0;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 3rem;
}

table caption {
  color: #356eaf;
  font-size: 1.3em;
  font-weight: normal;
  position: absolute;
  top: -2.25rem;
  left: 0.5rem;
}

tbody td {
  width: 100vw;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Balance Sheet</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <main>
      <section>
        <h1>
          <span class="flex">
            <span>AcmeWidgetCorp</span>
            <span>Balance Sheet</span>
          </span>
        </h1>
        <div id="years" aria-hidden="true">
          <span class="year">2019</span>
          <span class="year">2020</span>
          <span class="year">2021</span>
        </div>
        <div class="table-wrap">
          <table>
            <caption>Assets</caption>
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <td></td>
                <th><span class="sr-only year">2019</span></th>
                <th><span class="sr-only year">2020</span></th>
                <th class="current"><span class="sr-only year">2021</span></th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr class="data">
                <th>Cash <span class="description">This is the cash we currently have on hand.</span></th>
                <td>$25</td>
                <td>$30</td>
                <td class="current">$28</td>
              </tr>
              <tr class="data">
                <th>Checking <span class="description">Our primary transactional account.</span></th>
                <td>$54</td>
                <td>$56</td>
                <td class="current">$53</td>
              </tr>
              <tr class="data">
                <th>Savings <span class="description">Funds set aside for emergencies.</span></th>
                <td>$500</td>
                <td>$650</td>
                <td class="current">$728</td>
              </tr>
              <tr class="total">
                <th>Total <span class="sr-only">Assets</span></th>
                <td>$579</td>
                <td>$736</td>
                <td class="current">$809</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
          <table>
            <caption>Liabilities</caption>
            <thead>
              <tr>
              <td></td>
              <th><span class="sr-only">2019</span></th>
              <th><span class="sr-only">2020</span></th>
              <th><span class="sr-only">2021</span></th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr class="data">
                <th>Loans <span class="description">The outstanding balance on our startup loan.</span></th>
                <td>$500</td>
                <td>$250</td>
                <td class="current">$0</td>
              </tr>
              <tr class="data">
                <th>Expenses <span class="description">Annual anticipated expenses, such as payroll.</span></th>
                <td>$200</td>
                <td>$300</td>
                <td class="current">$400</td>
              </tr>
              <tr class="data">
                <th>Credit <span class="description">The outstanding balance on our credit card.</span></th>
                <td>$50</td>
                <td>$50</td>
                <td class="current">$75</td>
              </tr>
              <tr class="total">
                <th>Total <span class="sr-only">Liabilities</span></th>
                <td>$750</td>
                <td>$600</td>
                <td class="current">$475</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
          <table>
            <caption>Net Worth</caption>
            <thead>
              <tr>
              <td></td>
              <th><span class="sr-only">2019</span></th>
              <th><span class="sr-only">2020</span></th>
              <th><span class="sr-only">2021</span></th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr class="total">
                <th>Total <span class="sr-only">Net Worth</span></th>
                <td>$-171</td>
                <td>$136</td>
                <td class="current">$334</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </section>
    </main>
  </body>
</html>
```

Rendering:

[image]

Rendering with borders on td, to illustrate the width better (it is much less than 100vw - which should be 100% of the viewport, right?)

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I had a feeling the th elements (or other factors surrounding tables) might have something to do with things. I am not sure why they would prevent the td elements from displaying at 100vw though, could you explain?

Comment: Also is it best practice to share the CSS before the HTML in these questions? I had asked a prior question where someone swapped the the CSS with the HTML, I always thought it made sense to post the HTML first.

Comment: What Tim R did was to put your code inside a snippet that can be tested inside the browser. The snippet forces CSS to the top.

Comment: @Sanxofon oh I see, thank you. I'm still fairly new to this platform aha.

Comment: See my answer again. I've updated it with an explanation. If you like the answer please mark if as accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, some elements in HTML like `<td>`, `<tr>` or `<table>` already have some CSS properties set in the more "common" way. That is, some properties, such as `width`, have different default values in `<tr>` than other elements, for example a `<div>`.

In your question, although you have set a `width` value for `<td>`, but this element is located inside other parent elements (`<tr>` and `<table>`) that have properties defined by default, `width` in this case, which imposes its properties on its children.
Each type of HTML element has its default values for all the CSS properties that correspond to it.

You can see a long list of default values here:
[CSS Default Values Reference](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_default_values.php)

Try this:

```
table,tbody,tr {
  width: max-content;
}
tbody td {
  width: 100vw;
}
```

```css
table,tbody,tr {
  width: max-content;
}
tbody td {
  width: 100vw;
}
```

```html
          <table border=1>
            <tbody>
              <tr class="data">
                <th>Cash <span class="description">This is the cash we currently have on hand.</span></th>
                <td>$25</td>
                <td>$30</td>
                <td class="current">$28</td>
              </tr>
              <tr class="data">
                <th>Checking <span class="description">Our primary transactional account.</span></th>
                <td>$54</td>
                <td>$56</td>
                <td class="current">$53</td>
              </tr>
              <tr class="data">
                <th>Savings <span class="description">Funds set aside for emergencies.</span></th>
                <td>$500</td>
                <td>$650</td>
                <td class="current">$728</td>
              </tr>
              <tr class="total">
                <th>Total <span class="sr-only">Assets</span></th>
                <td>$579</td>
                <td>$736</td>
                <td class="current">$809</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply! So this does in fact set the width of the td's to be 100vw. But I am more interested in the explanation behind why they are not displaying with a width of 100vw the way that I had it. My goal is not so much achieve the 100vw per td, but rather understand why in my case it was not displaying at 100vw. The way I understand things it should display each td with a width of 100vw but it does not, so I'm hoping to fix my understanding.

Comment: For context I am just following a course to learn/master html/css - not actually trying to design a page according to some specifications. My goal is understanding, not so much a webpage.

Comment: Ok. I understand. I will add some general explanation of why this happens.

Comment: I re-read your answer, thank you for taking the time! It sheds a lot of light and makes sense. One follow up question - it would seem then that explicitly setting the width on the td does not override the default value given to it by its parent? The value imposed on it by its parent takes precedence? Because I thought that if you explicitly set a value on an element, it should take precedence and override any default values it inherits from its parent. (Sorry for the fine, nuanced questions, just want to make sure I thoroughly understand things)

Comment: No prob, i'ts a good question. As far as I know, there may be an overlap in order of priority. In the case of tables they behave (should behave) in a very particular way, different from other parent-child relationships. A TD should not leave its corresponding TR and this TR should not leave its TABLE. In CSS there are several types of element display, margins, paddings, etc. which can generate the same apparent effect in several ways or generate unpredictable effects. In the case of tables, they tend to behave in such a strange way in my experience that over time I have preferred to use grids.